# Python 2.7.9, wxpython 3.0.2, wx.grid and isColShown method issue

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have a wx.grid wxpython object and here is my error code :

> if self.my_grid.isColShown ( 1 ) : 
>  AttributeError: 'Grid' object has
>   no attribute 'isColShown'

Previously, I just call this method :

> self.my_grid.HideCol ( self.col )

That just run fine...

I tried on :
- Linux Mageia with Python 2.7, wxpython 3.0.2, 
- And under Windows 8 with WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3, wxPython3.0-win64-3.0.2.0-py27

But seems this method exists :
[official documentation wxpython for isColShown :](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.grid.Grid.html#wx.grid.Grid.IsColShown)

And the issue happends on both platform...

Do you think this it's a bug ? or I'm mistaken ?...

Note :
1 - my main development editor is Kdevelop 4.14.5, and crashes when i insert this method ...
2 - I googled this error message, and nothing shows up

Thanx in advance for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is named with a leading capital letter, `IsColShown`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is `IsColShown` (capital i).  A quick search of the [docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.grid.Grid.html?highlight=iscolshown) will help you with future problems like this. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right... I'm confused for a such mistake... 
I'm going to bed immediately... I'm off for tonight :) 
Thanks a lot guys, sorry for the disturb.